# Is there an alternative to azure for porting .net applications

Tags: azure, cloud, appharbor

We are having a .net application which we plan to move to the cloud. I hear a lot of people say if its .net app go for azure.
Are there any other alternatives for it in terms of ease of porting and pricing
Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon is a possible option - http://aws.amazon.com/net/

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check out [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). AppHarbor is a .Net PaaS built on top of Amazon. On the one hand you get the portability and infrastructure of Amazon but on the other they provide a number of the rich services that Azure offers such as background tasks & load balancing plus some that it doesn't like 3rd party add-ons, dead-simple deployment and more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to port code to .Net to run in Azure.  Pretty much every runtime/language that works on Windows Server 2008 works on Azure.  I've put a lot of native (C/C++) code up for various projects.

There are a lot of docs on how to run Java, PHP, etc. as well.

Comment: Maybe you should read the question again. He does already have a .net application.